# How do I change the "root" directories name in JTree?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a simple implementation of JTree:

```
tree1 = new JTree(LibObj.collectionToStringArray(LibObj.books));
tree1.setRootVisible(true);
scrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(tree1);
scrollPane2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 300));
panel.add(scrollPane2);
```

LibObj.collectionToStringArray(LibObj.books) is a method in another class that takes a collection and turns it into an array of strings

Everything is displaying as expected but the root directory is named "Root". How do I change the name? (I want it to be called Books)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the constructor JTree(TreeNode node) would give you the chance to create your own root node.

Just like this:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root node name");
for( String book : booksArray ) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode bookNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(book);
    rootNode.add(bookNode);
}

tree1 = new JTree(rootNode);
tree1.setRootVisible(true);
[...]
```